# MVC3 jquery post serialize array

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-selectors

In my website there is a `table`, in every `td`, there is a `div` with `<input>` inside.
I run over the table and serialize every div and post it to the server.

```
        for (var r = 0; r < tbodyRow.length; r++) {
            var tbodyCols = tbodyRow[r].cells;
            for (var c = 0; c < tbodyCols.length; c++) {
                row = r + 1;
                cell = c + 1;
                div = $("#tbody tr:nth-child(" + row + ") td:nth-child(" + cell + ") :input").serialize();
                if (div != "") {
                    $.post("../Contoller/Action?Mode=" + Mode, div, function () { });
                }
                tbodyCounter++;
            };
        };
```

and in the server - the action have an object as parameter that get it.

I would like to post all the list of the object (that i have in the divs) just once 
and get it as `List<T>` in the server side.
is it possible ?

Comment: explain in more detail exactly what objective is. One call only to server for all data? If so one object sent via JSON would work?

Comment: Charlietfl, the object is employee, every employee have inputs (client side), for every div, I serialize the inputs and send it to the server. I need to concatenate all the serialization so i will send it to the server just one time and get it in the server as a list

Comment: some sample html would help. Not sure why wrapping whole table in `form` and serializing form won't work as suggested by @Shyju

Comment: Because I did it already, but i don't know how to get it as a List<T> in the action.

Comment: OK..  code you posted, and subject, suggested you were needing jQuery help. Sounds like issue has nothing to do with jQuery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, model binding allows to do that. Refer below article

http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/

Also refer below one for introduction

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Have the inputs inside the form tag and serialize form and send it.

```
$.post("@Url.Action("YourAction","YourController")",
                            $("#yourFormID").serailize(),function(data){

});
```

In the controller, you can use the model /viewmodel which your view was strongly typed to , as the parameter so that MVC model binding will bind that posted data to it.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult YourAction(YourViewModel model)
{

 //do something
}
```

Comment: this is what i did already, but i do to every div in the table.

Comment: I would like to concatanate all the div to one element and post it to the server, so the server will get it as a collection